# Drawbacks of using jInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

For all my previous projects I used `JFrames` in which most of the new tasks are opened on new `JFrames` on top of a main `JFrame`. But for my next project the customer requested new windows to be opened inside the `JFrame` ( he was referring to `JInternalFrame`).

What I want to know is is there any drawbacks when using `JInternalFrame`? as Sun specifies it's a `LightWeight Component` when compared to `JFrame`.

Comment: "For all my previous projects I used JFrames in which most of the new tasks are opened on new JFrames on top of a main JFrame." Generally an application should only have a single JFrame and child windows should be JDialogs.

Comment: Have you considered using a docking framework (like the Netbeans or Eclipse app platforms)?

Comment: @camickr:- What you prefer? JDialog or JInternalFrame

Comment: @Michael:- Yes i'm already using Netbeans and Eclipse both. this was just a matter of what should I use for secondary windows that pops up :)

Comment: A JDialog an JInternalFrame are used for two different purposes. You use whatever is appropriate for the requirement. My comment was specifically about using multiple JFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as Sun specifies it's a LightWeight Component when compared to JFrame.

A JFrame is basically a lightweight component as well. The border and title is an OS related object and you can't change the behaviour of any of those features. However, all Swing components are added to the content pane of the frame which is a JPanel.

A JInternalFrame also uses a JPanel as a content pane, so, any Swing component that you can add to a JFrame you can add to a JInternalFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to add your internal frames to a `JDesktopPane`. The [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) has a list of rules to check. You might look at an open-source project like that uses internal frames, like [SQirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), to see if they needed very many workarounds.